# how to insert string into string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, split, substring

i have string that look like this

```
"4300000"
```

i want insert "." for every 3 digit starting from behind of my string. so my string will look like this

```
 "4.300.000"
```

after adding dot. i tried using implode() and str_split() method before but end up splitting the string from the front.

```
implode(".",(str_split($type->base_salary, 3)))
```

any solutions? or other method that will splitting the string from behind?

thanks before !

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
$output = number_format("4300000", 0, "", ".");
//output will be  "4.300.000"
```

You can read more about `number_format` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: better solution :D